# How do I transfer formatted text from Word to Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

The below code is copied data from MS Word (content control) to Excel. However, when I copy text with bullet and paste into Excel, it removes the bullets and pastes the text only.

How can I copy bullets from the content control?

```
Sub getWordFormData()
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim CCtl As Word.ContentControl
Dim myFolder As String, strFile As String
Dim myWkSht As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long

myFolder = "enter folder path" '<< enter you folder path for the word document

If Dir(myFolder & "\" & "*.*") = "" Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "The folder is empty."
    Exit Sub
End If

Set myWkSht = ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
Range("A1") = "Test 1"
Range("B1") = "Test 2"
Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True

i = myWkSht.Cells(myWkSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
strFile = Dir(myFolder & "\*.docx", vbNormal)

While strFile <> ""
    i = i + 1

    Set myDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=myFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)

    With myDoc
        j = 0
        For Each CCtl In .ContentControls
            j = j + 1
            myWkSht.Cells(i, j) = CCtl.Range.Text
        Next
        myWkSht.Columns.AutoFit
    End With

    myDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    strFile = Dir()
Wend

wdApp.Quit
Set myDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set myWkSht = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: hi, i believe that u have to  do a copy / pastespecial. i didnt  test, but something like "CCtl.Range.Text.copy" and next "myWkSht.Cells(i, j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues" . good luck

Comment: its giving compile error on text CCtl.Range.Text.copy (invalid qualifier)

Comment: try with CCtl.Range.Copy

Comment: not worked. error: expected function or variable.

Comment: ive made a word test file and theres no error. did u put             "CCtl.Range.Copy" and "myWkSht.Cells(i, j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues". it gives error in witch line ?

Comment: Not working: I am puting like this myWkSht.Cells(i, j).Value = CCtl.Range.Text

CCtl.Range.Copy

Next

myWkSht.Cells(i, j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


myWkSht.Columns.AutoFit

End With'''

Answer (score 0):

try with this block

```
With myDoc
    j = 0
    For Each CCtl In .ContentControls
        j = j + 1
        CCtl.Range.Copy
        myWkSht.Cells(i, j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Next
    myWkSht.Columns.AutoFit
End With
```

Comment: thanks its working, but now the problem is its not pasting in all the bullets in single cell any idea to improve?

Comment: u are selecting one control each time with "For Each CCtl In .ContentControls. u must select multiple to copy all in once